# Days that cashier will work

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

A cashier wants to work five days a week, but he wants to have at least one of Saturday and Sunday off.

How many ways can he choose the days he will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Split up the problem into easier *cases*. If the cashier  wants the whole weekend off, there is $1$ way only. How many ways with Saturday off but not Sunday? How many with Sunday off but not Saturday? Add the three numbers.